# jvectormap meging countries with common region in JS Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, jvectormap

We have created a js file for displaying JVectorMap Africa map using Converter.py. Now we want to merge few countries together and put a common label for the region. We opened the js file and merged the Path attribute of those countries and put the common name for region.

"South Africa": { "path": "M197.62,397.95l-3.9,-4.3l-2.22,-4.46l-4.64,-19.99l-0.89,-10.73l-5.31,-7.66l-4.39,-11.15l-4.64,-5.75l-0.31,-4.08l5.82,-1.98l3.53,0.17l3.34,2.61l24.61,-0.57l4.16,2.87l14.08,0.85l15.53,-3.8l3.57,0.33l1.85,1.09l-4.66,1.22l-3.36,2.13l-2.43,-2.31l-13.69,2.78l-0.17,21.08l-5.74,0.69l-0.0,40.71l-4.87,3.03l-2.91,0.43l-5.94,-1.59l-1.05,-2.66l-2.3,-1.72l-3.09,2.77Z", "name": "South Africa" },

This solution is working fine on IE but not in Firefox. Can anyone tell us how can we merge them so that it will work on all browsers.

Comment: What kind of error do you have in Firefox?

Comment: Not getting any error...but if i am merging CountryA and CountryB, then either it is not rendering both the countries or 2nd country in the map. I also noticed that path attribute value starts with 'M' and ends with 'Z'. In above example M197.62 and 2.77Z. But when i am merging i will have 2 entries for 'M' and 2 enteries for 'Z'. Is that can be an issue?

Comment: Should not be a problem, I did the same several times. Is there any way you can show the actual demo or at lease code?

Comment: I have downloaded the code from [link](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap) </br> If you run index.html it will create world map. I want to merge Namibia and South Africa as one region in Africa. I copied the value in PATH attribute of Namibia and append it in path attribute of SouthAfrica and then remove entire entry of Namibia. By doing this merging was working fine on IE9 but not in firefox.

Comment: After merging "South Africa" entry will become <br/> "ZA": { "path": "M467.06,373.27l-0.13,-0.29l0.01,-1.58l-0.02,-0.12l-0.71,-1.64l0.59,-0.37l0.14,-0.26l-0.07,-2.13l-0.05,-0.15l-1.63,-2.58l-1.25,-2.31l-1.71,-3.37l0.88,-0.98l0.7,0.52l0.39,1.08l0.23,0.19l1.1,0.19l1.55,0.51l0.14,0.01l1.35,-0.2l0.11,-0.04l2.24,-1.39l0.14,-0.25l0.0,-9.4l0.16,0.09l1.39,2.38l-0.22,1.53l0.04,0.19l0.56,0.94l0.3,0.14l1.79,-0.27l0.1...

Comment: Got the answer...i will update here once i completely verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG Path string consists of M, L and Z (in both cases). Capital letters for absolute and small letters for relative. You can find the more details in below link:
http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Paths

For absolute you can straight away merge them but for relative you need to put some value between 2 paths so that the 2nd path start from the correct place.